# From [a,b] to [$0$,$1$]

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, uniform-convergence

I was checking an exercise and it's proof and I couldn't understand why the interval [a,b] can be 'replaced' by [0,1].

This is the exercise:

Prove that every continuous function f:[a,b]$\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of even polynomials if and only if (a,b) doesn't contain the origin.

Proof:

Suppose (a,b) doesn't contain the origin.
And for simplicity consider $[0,1]$ instead of [a,b].

.

. (and the proof continue)

.

So why is it equivalent to work with $[0,1]$ ?

Is there a proof to show that $[0,1] \Leftarrow \Rightarrow [a,b]$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we have the result for $[0,1].$ If now $f\in C([0,b]),$ define $g:[0,1] \to [0,b]$ by setting $g(x) = bx.$ Then $f\circ g \in C([0,1]).$ So there exists a sequence $P_n$ of even polynomials such that $ P_n \to f\circ g$ uniformly on $[0,1].$ This implies $P_n\circ g^{-1} \to f$ uniformly on $[0,b].$ Since each $P_n\circ g^{-1}$ is an even polynomial, we have the result for $[0,b].$

If now $0<a<b$ and $f\in C([a,b]),$ we can extend $f$ to a continuous function $F$ on $[0,b],$ simply by setting $F(x) = f(a)$ for $x\in [0,a).$ By the above, there is a sequence $P_n$ of even polynomials such that $ P_n \to F$ uniformly on $[0,b].$ This of course implies $ P_n \to F$ uniformly on $[a,b].$ Since $F=f$ on $[a,b],$ we have the desired result for $[a,b].$

The result for intervals $[a,b]$ with $a<b\le 0$ follows easily from this.

Comment: Only answer that works!

Comment: only answer I have no idea what it means with his hint @Bananach

Comment: @AnneliseToft I edited my answer to a more complete solution.

Comment: Argument is simple and powerful at the same time. It also avoids having to find mappings between $[0, 1]$ and $[a, b] $ which preserve even nature of polynomials.+1

Comment: $F$ is defined by $F:[0,a) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and given by $F(x)=f(a)$?

Comment: @AnneliseToft Right.

Comment: and why did you say $P_n \to F$ uniformly on $[0,b]$? I think should be [0,a) instead of [0,b] ?

Comment: No, certainly not. $F$ is continuous on $[0,b],$ so now use the first paragraph.

Comment: and how could be $F$ continuous on $[0,b]$ is $F$ it's just defined on $[0,a)$ and $a<b$ ?

Comment: Please read the proof slowly and carefully.

Comment: I am doing it.. 

Comment: Finally I fully understand it, but I had to draw the functions f and F to visualize.

Answer (score 1):

Because $f(x) := a+(b-a)x$ is a continuous bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[a,b]$.

Comment: Even polynomials are not mapped to even polynomials though under this transformation

Comment: so this function doesn't work? why not? @Bananach

Comment: Try it out! For example $ x^2$ on $(0,1) $, which is even, get's mapped to $(\frac{x-a}{b-a})^2=\frac{1}{b-a}^2 (x^2-2ax+a^2) $ which is not even

Comment: @Bananach you're right. thanks

Comment: Actually, the worry about even polynomials is irrelevent.  Wo are considering if it is true on *that* interval.  But *that* interval is arbitrary.  The only things significant about *that* interval is that the origin is not on it.  So if we can show it is true for  (0,1) the argument will hold true for (a,b) And we aren't showing the *same* polynomials are even.  We are showing there *are* even polynomials.  If (0,1) must have even polynomials then (a,b) will have even polynomials (but probably different ones).  ... to be continue ...

Comment: The one huge red warning sign I have though, is that 0 is the endpoint of (0,1) but not of (a,b).  That might not matter but if we have $x \rightarrow 0$ we'll have $y \rightarrow 0 = -y \rightarrow 0$ and ... oh, I guess that doesn't really matter as $-x \rightarrow -a$ means $f(x) \rightarrow f(a) = f(-a) \leftarrow f(-x)$ is fine....

Comment: @Bananach the worry about even polynomials does't matter, as fleablood said

Comment: The worry about even polynomials is all that matters. If you are able to make sense (and rigour) of the previous comments be my guest, but I think you would do yourself a favor to follow zhw.'s approach instead

Comment: Actually, I think maybe we should actually look at what the proof in the text actually does and says.  The question is about whether it is legitimate for the text to say "And for simplicity consider [0,1] instead of [a,b]."  That depends on what the proof actual does.

Answer (score 1):

It should be "intuitively obvious"  That $0$, $1$ and the distance $|1|$ are arbitrary and can be replaced with $a,b$ so that $b > a$ and $|b -a| > 0$.

More formally $g:(a,b) \rightarrow (0, 1)$ so that $g(a) =0$ and $g(b)$ so that for $x =$ some point a proportion, $p$, of the way between $a$ and $b$ and $g(x)$ is the point the same proportion of the way between $0$ and $1$ is a bijection.

To actually nail the jello to the wall:  The proportion $p$ is $\frac {x-a}{b-a}$ so the function $g(x) = \frac {x-a}{b-a}$ is a bijection between $[a,b]$ and $[0,1]$ with $g^{-1}(y) = y*(b-a) + a$.  (For $a \le x \le b$ then $0 \le x-a \le b-a$ and $0 \le \frac {x-a}{b-a} \le 1$ so $g:[a,b]\rightarrow [0,1]$. And if $0 \le k \le 1$ then $x = k*(b-a) + a \in [a,b]$ and $g(x) = \frac {(k*(b-a) + a) - a}{b-a} = k$ so $g$ is surjective.  And if $a\le x < y\le b$ then $g(x) = \frac {x-a}{b-a} < \frac {y-a}{b-a} = g(y)$ so $g$ is injective.)

..... so in this case $f(x)$ is continuous on $(a,b)$.  Then $h(y) = f(y(b-a) + a)=f(g^{-1}(x)) = f(x)$ is continuous on $(0,1)$.

Comment: are even polynomials mapped to even polynomials though under this function?

Comment: no, they are not.  Let me think about this.

Comment: R to (-1,1) via $f(x) = \frac x{|x| + 1} $ is a bijction that does.  As (a,b) does not contain 0 (wolog 0 < a < b) we can stretch (a, (a+b)/2] to [2a/(a+b),1) via $f(x) = a/x; $. then we co stretch [(a+ b)/2, b) to (0, 2a/(a+b)] via ... stretching it the other way...g(x) = 2a/(a+b) - f(b-x). So $h(x) = f(x)| x \le (a+b)/2; h(x) = g(x)| x \ge (a+b)/2$.  I *think* that preserves even polynomials.

Comment: I don't understand your notation, how is defined h(x)? is has a ; in the definition? or a $ \vert $ is missing?

Comment: h(x) equal f(x) for x in the first half of the interval and h(x) = g(x) for the second.  A better idea but it's hand wavy is if $0 < a < b$ we can just use $f(x) = \frac {x-a}{b-a}$ for $x > 0$ and $f(x) = - \frac {-x -a}{b-a}$ for $x < -a$ and this is a continuous bijection of $(\infty, -a) \cup (a, \infty)$ to $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ that simply throws away [-a,a].  It is continuous as 0 is not in the set.   even polynomials are kept.

Comment: ok so f(x):(a, (a+b)/2] $ \rightarrow$ [2a/(a+b),1) and g(x): [(a+ b)/2, b)$ \rightarrow$ (0, 2a/(a+b)]?

Comment: ok so the last idea is better, which one should I consider then? because the second one is hand wavy..what does that mean?

Comment: Forget everything.  If (a,b) does not contain 0 then it can be stretched to (0,1) if we can argue whatever the argument was about continuous functions and even polynomials on (0,1) we can argue it on (a,b) as (a,b) and (0,1) are essentially the same.  That (a,b) will have *different* polynomials is not relevant.  You build the polynomials based on the intervals.  You *don't* build the polynomials on one interval and transfport them. You follow the same argumnt and know that you can build a *new* set of polynomials on *any* interval.

Comment: wow what a reasoning thanks @fleablood it's really helpful

Comment: @fleablood The problem is to show if the result for even polynomials holds for $[0,1],$ then the result for even polynomials holds for any $[a,b]$ not containing $0.$ I really don't understand your line of reasoning.

Comment: First of all it does't hold for closed intervals. Only open intervals not containing zero.  Second.  There'There's absolutely nothing special about (0,1). If it holds true for (0,1) it will hold true for any other open interval not containing 0.

Comment: @fleablood  The result holds for any $[a,b]$ such that $0\notin (a,b).$ Aside from that you keep saying "it will hold", but I haven't seen a proof. The proof in your answer is wrong. Your first line, for example, seems to miss the point that $0\notin (a,b)$ is crucial.

Comment: The question wasn't about proving the result but about whether it is sufficient to prove it on (0,1). the text took it as obvious. I didn't try to prove the result. I explained why it is sufficient to consider (a,b) equiv to (0,1). There's obviously a bijection.  One assumes when one actually reads whatever the text has as a proof (I have *no* idea what it will be and the OP never asked or commented) that it will not rely on anything specific about (0,1) other than that 0 not in (0,1). If it does not rely on anything specific then the proof for (a,b) will be equivilent. If it does, it won't..

Answer (score -1):

Yes, actually you can map $[a,b]$ to $[0,1]$ using the following function: $x \mapsto \frac{x - a}{b - a}$. This is a bijection between the two intervals, and it is also a continuous function as you can check.

Comment: Even polynomials are not mapped to even polynomials though under this transformation

Comment: That's not relevent. Whatever you can prove about general even polynomials and their need to exist and conditions they have on interval (0,1) you can prove about a *different* set of even polynomials on intervals (a,b).  You don't need to *translate* one set of polynomials into another.

Comment: Just because the argument can be fixed does not mean it is not relevant that there is something to fix. If it suffices to consider $(0,1) $ because there is a bijection with $(a, b) $ then why does the same argument not work for any interval? What is it that breaks this line of argument for intervals that do contain the origin?

Comment: In short, the argument the fact that there is a bijection is irrelevant. The only way this alone would suffice as justification would be if even polynomials were indeed mapped to even polynomials. Hence, I thought it was worth pointing out this is not the case

Comment: what do you think @fleablood ?

Comment: The even polynomials that will estimate f on [0,1] do not need to (and will not) map to even polynomials on [a,b].  But that is not the point.  The proof in the text will prove that we will be able to find even polynomials that will estimate f so long as 0 not in (0,1).  The proof will, presumably, not rely upon the actual values of (0,1).  Therefore we can use the same reasoning to show we can find *different* even polynomials that will estimate f on [a,b].  Of course, we will have to actuall *see* the proof the text is going to produce.

Comment: Nor will the proof rely upon the exact nature of the function $f$ (only that it is continuous) the exact polynomials that we do prove exist (other than they are even) or the exact natural of [a,b] (other than) $0 \not \in (a,b)$.

Answer (score -1):

This can be proved in two stages:

- Prove $[0,1]\sim [a,1+a]$ (translation)
- Prove $[0,1]\sim [0,a]$ (scale)

Combining these gives the result.