# Even polynomials on $[0,1]$ instead of $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, compactness

This question is 'part' of another question that I asked here days ago.(Althoug this is a new question)

I've the following exercise:

Prove that every continuous function f:[a,b]$\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of even polynomials if and only if (a,b) doesn't contain the origin.

Proof:

Suppose (a,b) doesn't contain the origin.
And for simplicity consider $[0,1]$ instead of [a,b].

It's equivalent to work with $[0,1]$ because of this proof by @zhw at [From [a,b] to [$0$,$1$]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279493/from-a-b-to-0-1/2279573#2279573):

Suppose we have the result for $[0,1].$ If now $f\in C([0,b]),$ define $g:[0,1] \to [0,b]$ by setting $g(x) = bx.$ Then $f\circ g \in C([0,1]).$ So there exists a sequence $P_n$ of even polynomials such that $ P_n \to f\circ g$ uniformly on $[0,1].$ This implies $P_n\circ g^{-1} \to f$ uniformly on $[0,b].$ Since each $P_n\circ g^{-1}$ is an even polynomial, we have the result for $[0,b].$

If now $0<a<b$ and $f\in C([a,b]),$ we can extend $f$ to a continuous function $F$ on $[0,b],$ simply by setting $F(x) = f(a)$ for $x\in [0,a).$ By the above, there is a sequence $P_n$ of even polynomials such that $ P_n \to F$ uniformly on $[0,b].$ This of course implies $ P_n \to F$ uniformly on $[a,b].$ Since $F=f$ on $[a,b],$ we have the desired result for $[a,b].$

But, I don't know how the result for intervals $[a,b]$ with $a<b\le 0$ will be?

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Once you have a proof for the case $0\leq a'<b',$ then for the case $a<b\leq 0$ let $b'=-a$ and $a'=-b.$  And let $g(x)=f(-x).$ And apply the case $0\leq a'<b'$ to $g$.

Comment: When you copy a proof verbatim from another poster, as you did with my proof above, you should give a link to it. I've edited you post to include the link.

Comment: ok and to give you credits too @zhw.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet If I let $g(x)=f(-x)$, how will I apply the case $0 \leq a'<b'$ to $g$ .Because I think in the case $0 \leq a'<b'$  we didn't use $g$, we just expand f to F and then we obtain the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $0\not \in (a,b)$, extend $f$ to a continuous even function on $[-c,c]=[-\max(|a|,|b|),\max (|a|,|b|)]$ and let $(g_n)_n$ be a sequence of polynomials  converging  uniformly to $f$ on $[-c,c]$.  Let $h_n(x)=(g_n(x)+g_n(-x))/2.$ Then $(h_n)_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[-c,c]$ and, a fortiori, on $[a,b]$.

If $0\in (a,b)$ consider the case $f(x)=x-a$ which is not an even function.  A point-wise limit, and a fortiori, a uniform limit, of a sequence of even functions is even.

Comment: seems like you didn't follow your hint from before (this answers looks more difficult) 

Comment: I didn't follow my hint. It seemed you had 3/4 of an answer already. My hint was about the rest. But I didn't understand your difficulty so I put up a general A.